# Using mixer on linux(PulseAudio) get java.lang.IllegalStateException when opening a line

Tags: java, ubuntu, pulseaudio

This is i found mixer on Ubuntu 11.04

```
Name: PulseAudio Mixer 
Vendor: IcedTea 
Version: 0.02 
Description: the ear-candy mixer
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "PooledThread-14" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-20" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-7" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-8" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-19" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-31" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-9" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-10" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-17" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-12" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-11" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-18" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-13" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-16" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-15" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-25" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-21" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-29" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-26" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-23" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-24" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-22" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-27" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-28" Exception in thread "PooledThread-3" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-5" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
Exception in thread "PooledThread-6" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:650)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    at sound.SoundManager.threadStarted(SoundManager.java:325)
    at util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:141)
```

I create game using JAVA when i test with linux(ubuntu 11.04) the mixer only have 1 line so i cannot play sound simultaneously. I got from net that pulseAudio have -1 line thats mean its have unlimited line so i tried to using that mixer. But when i opening an line i got that error.

How to fix that???

Answer (score 2):

I've got a similar error. It seems that the PulseAudio Mixer is not thread safe in this manner. I solved it by externally synchonizing on the AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine() call.

Comment: For me, it didn't work until I stretched the synchronization over `line.open` and `line.start`, too.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue as well on my linux box (mint) which was not happening on windows. I found that switching from openJDK and JRE to sunJDK and JRE solved my problem.

You can go here https://askubuntu.com/questions/21131/how-to-correctly-remove-openjdk-and-jre-and-set-the-system-use-only-and-only-sun for more information.